# Combine the values of 2 drop-down list in 1 MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the code below, which I want to use to combine the **month** and **date** values of the drop-down list, in a MySQL query, so I can filter by date.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label class="custom-select">
<select name="q">
<option value="">Selecione o Mês:</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 1''">Jan</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 2''">Feb</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 3''">Mar</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 4''">Apr</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 5''">May</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 6''">Jun</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 7''">Jul</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 8''">Aug</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 9''">Sep</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 10''">Oct</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 11''">Nov</option>
<option value="MONTH(post_date) = 12''">Dez</option>
</select>
</label>
<label class="custom-select">
<select name="q">
<option value="">Selecione o Ano:</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2013">2013</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014">2014</option>
<option value="AND YEAR(post_date) = 2015">2015</option>
</select>
</label>
<input name="submit2" id="submit2" style="margin-left: 15px;" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>

<?php 
if ($_POST['q'] == '') {
    $q = 'YEAR(post_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())';
}
else {
    $q = $_POST['q'] ;
}

$query=mysql_query("SELECT *, 'Yield'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND ".$q." 
LIMIT 0, 2500")
?>
```

This is not working, I get the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014

Can someone help. Thanks

Comment: Your code is wide open for sql injection and also you have 2 AND operators in the query 1 AND is hardcoded in the query and 1 AND is coming from the POST request

Comment: A helpful method of debugging this type of error is to `echo` the exact query you're passing to the DB server.

Comment: The problem is passing the submit values to the query

Comment: Check the position of the single quotes on the month value `MONTH(post_date) = 1''`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad way to solve the problem. Among other things, you're depending on the field values to come back in the right order, which isn't guaranteed. It's also trivial to attack this with SQL injection.

But to answer your question: the `''` after the `MONTH()` clause is probably messing things up. Your query is probably coming out as

```
SELECT *, 'Yield'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND MONTH(post_date) = 6''AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014
```

But there's no easy way to fix that without making bad code worse.

Comment: I made a mistake in that part, but that's not the error. What I get is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND YEAR(post_date) = 2014

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the *latest* version of your code? Otherwise we're just guessing.